# What is the difference between importing from `foo.py` and importing from `foo/__init__.py` in Python

Tags: python, import, pylint

If `foo.py` and `foo/__init__.py` are the same and do not contain relative import. And if you import with the following :

```
from foo import X #  (or import foo)
```

I thought there was no difference. I did that quite a number of time when a file become too big and when I want to burst it into a package and multiple files. But this is not really the case as evidenced by [this commit](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2654/commits/314aecebd201efe64843a29aa7e43513629a4b8d) failing the [tests for pylint](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/PCManticore/pylint/builds/21477041/job/4xj3nypm1okdbfur).

```
pylint/utils.py → pylint/utils/__init__.py
File renamed without changes.
```

It makes 3 functional tests fail (`logging_format_interpolation`, `deprecated_methods_py3` and `redundant_unittest_assert`). This is true rebase after rebase and each time the commit from the master branch was working fine. I also use the `--recreate` option when launching tox.

The stdlib.py file that contain those checkers does not seem to even import something from `pylint.utils` (it uses `pylint.checker.utils`), so I have no idea why it would break, yet it does.

This file contain some function starting with an underscore (`_function_name`) could it be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no difference. The pylint master branch was just not passing the tests suite for a very long time, see [this comment](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2654#issuecomment-453834319).